# Unable to create array in MongoDB - MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am working on Ticket system module using MERN stack. I want to create an array named "message" when the time of creating Ticket.

when user click on Create Ticket button we are storing some data like order ID, service, payment, transaction ID, subject along with user Message(user can write briefly about the issue) in MongoDB. once it was stored then admin can reply to that message so we need to create theses are in one document.

I can able to store other fields like order ID, service name, subject but I didn't know how to create array for storing messages.

Please help me.

**This is my Ticket Scheema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./userScheema');


const TicketScheema=new mongoose.Schema({
    subject:{
        type:String
    },
    request:{
        type:String
    },
    orderID:{
        type:Number
    },
    descs:[
        {
            desc:
            {
                type:Array,
                required:true
            }
        }
    ],
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    role:{
        type:String
    },
    payment:{
        type:String
    },
    transactionID:{
        type:Number
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        default:"Not Answered"
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:User,
        required:true
    }
})

const Ticket=mongoose.model("Ticket",TicketScheema);
module.exports=Ticket;
```

**Express Router:**

```
router.post("/submitTicket",authenticateUser,async(req,res)=>{
     try {
        let user=req.root_user[0]._id.toString();
        let role=req.root_user[0].role.toString();
        let name=req.root_user[0].name.toString();
        let {subject,request,orderID,desc,payment,transactionID}=req.body;
        let resp=await new Ticket({
            subject,
            request,
            orderID,
            desc, //here desc is the user message, want to store it as array
            payment,
            transactionID,
            user,
            role,
            name
          
        })
        resp.save();
        res.status(201).send(resp)
     } catch (error) {
         res.status(400).send("Unable to create Ticket")
     }
 })
```

**Front End:**

```
  const createTicket =async()=>{
        let resp=await fetch('/submitTicket',{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                subject,request,orderID,desc:Desc,payment:payment1,transactionID:TransactionID
            })
        })
        if(resp.status==201)
        {
            alert("Ticket Created")
        }
    }
```

Am new to MERN, please help me

Comment: The first time you create the Ticket, you store the description field as an array with the first description or if there is no value store as empty array. Later descriptions, can be added to the array in an _update_ operation.

Comment: description field is mandatory, when user creating the ticket first time, we should store it as an array. then later admin can view it and replay to that description(message).

Comment: @prasad_ please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the `descs` property as:

```
descs:[
    {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
],
```

And then add a new property to the field with:

```
let resp = new Ticket({
  subject,
  request,
  orderID,
  payment,
  transactionID,
  user,
  role,
  name,
});

resp.descs.push(desc)

await resp.save()

res.status(201).send(resp)
```